# Apache Mina TLS client - Camel

Tags: ssl, tcp, apache-mina

I am using Apache Mina (Mina2 - Netty not available to use - don't ask why :P) to create a TCP Client which connects to a TCP server over TLS.

Here's the SSLContext:

Here's my blueprint xml route:

```
    <route id="ReadMQ">
        <from uri="jmsep://topic:test/014/data" />
        <process ref="readIt"></process>
        <to
            uri="mina2:tcp://SOMEHOST:38332?sync=true;sslContextParameters=#mySSL;minaLogger=true" />

    </route>
```

cert.pem contains both the key and cert in it.

When Nina tries to connect to the endpoint, it server closes the connection with this error:

```
            System.IO.IOException: The handshake failed due to an unexpected      packet format.
                       at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReadFrame(Byte[] buffer, Int32 readBytes, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
```

Looking at error, it feels like Mina is not connecting with the correct protocol?

Here's what Mina says:

```
            SEVERE: Exception on receiving message from address:     SOMEHOST:38332 using connector: (nio socket connector: managedSessionCount: 0)
            Throwable occurred: java.io.IOException: An existing connection     was forcibly closed by the remote host.
```

Also, when I use the s_client this way:
 openssl s_client -connect SOMEHOST:38332 -cert cert.pem -key cert.pem -state -debug

It goes head and does the SSL handshake with exchange of certificates.

Any clues what I am missing here?

Answer (score 0):

The key into keystore and cert into truststore were not getting added because they were PEM format. The server would request for client certificate and the client's certificate chain would be empty and hence the error. 
To solve this I created a JKS format keystore and imported the p12 file ( created using the pem files ) and it worked.